# Simplifying PowerShell pipeline splitting data from command output

Tags: powershell, pipe

I'm trying to do some processing on the output from a psftp "ls" command.  Basically, I want to put all of the file names that match certain conditions into an array.  I have this:

```
PS C:\path\to\pwd> $a = & "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\psftp.exe" -l myusername -batch -pw mypassword -b sftpbatch.txt myserver | where {$_.split(" ", [StringSplitOptions]'RemoveEmptyEntries')[0] -eq "-rw-r--r--"} | select-object {$_.split(" ", [StringSplitOptions]'RemoveEmptyEntries')[8]}
```

(If you want more details about that command, I can provide them.  The output is very similar to the output of the "ls" command in PowerShell.)

It seems to me that I can do better by selecting the split first, then filtering it with where.  When I try this:

```
$a = & <# ... #> | select-object {$_.split(" ", [StringSplitOptions]'RemoveEmptyEntries')} | where { $_[0] -eq "-rw-r--r--" }
```

I get

```
Unable to index into an object of type System.Management.Automation.PSObject.
```

How can I simplify this?

Comment: You probably need to run a regex on `psftp.exe`'s stdout. Post the output of the command and specify the text you want to extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
$a = & <#...#>| % {$b = $_ -split ' '|?{$_}; if($b[0] -eq '-rw-r--r--'){$b[8]}}
```

If you are placing this in a script, I would replace the alias `%` with `Foreach-Object`, and the alias `?` with `Where-Object`

**Edit:**

Here is a more pipeline-oriented approach:

```
'-rw-r--r-- 1 2 3   4 5 6 7 test.txt'| 
    select @{Name='Words'; Expression={$_ -split ' '|where {$_}}}|
    where {$_.Words[0] -eq "-rw-r--r--"}|
    foreach {$_.Words[8]}
```

Comment: Cool, that does it.  Out of curiosity, is it possible to do this using an all-pipes approach like I'd originally tried?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you can do it with all piped commands; it's just a little more verbose. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again.  I can't yet vote up your answer, but if I could, I would!